# PhantomJS 2.1.1 ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`'

Tags: jquery, angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am using phanthomJS with karma in agular testing, I added`{pattern: "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js", watched: false,  }`, in karma.conf.js file. When running the test case, I am getting bellow error.

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
>     SyntaxError: Invalid character: '`'
>     at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/vendor.js:79356

Can some one suggest a solution to fix this issue.

I see that character in jquery file, Chrome doesnot complain but PhantomJS does

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to run angular karma tests which has jQuery dependency